# Microsoft Teams: How to set the author of a chat message?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

The [Teams Beta Chat API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-chatmessage?view=graph-rest-beta) allows posting messages to a channel. Good. I want to specify the author of this message (which shall not be me, but an arbitraryly chosen user). Can this be done? How?

**More context**

We need to set the author in a migration scenario where messages from another system must be migrated to Teams.

The [documentation of the chatMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/chatmessage?view=graph-rest-beta) resource type (used by the `/chatmessage` endpoint) lists some properties as read-only, but the `from` field is none of them. This leaves the impression that the author can be set.

This is the POST body I tried:

```
{
  "body": {
    "contentType": "html",
    "content": "Hello World",
    "from": {
      "user": {
        "displayName": "Heinrich Ulbricht"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This gives me a 500 response from the server. I also tried setting the id of the user. Same result: error 500.

Removing the `from` property succeeds and posts the message. This is the endpoint I used: `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/<id>/channels/<id>/messages`

So is it possible to set the author of a chat message?

Comment: You might need to get delegated permission from the user to post the message. Currently, that's the only option to send message which shows from author.

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT This would mean that it would be "me" again, but with another "me", right? And shouldn't it work for myself then without problems (it does not)?

Comment: It should work for you. Could you please add screenshot of what you are getting right now and what you are expecting?

Comment: can some one please share the github samples to test this beta apis please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not yet possible to impersonate another user in any API, Graph or Bot. We are planning to do this at some point but it will require elevated privilege and the ability to annotate the message as having been created by an API as opposed to a user and making it possible to audit for these types of annotations later. Otherwise it’s a huge security hole.

Building these underlying capabilities is why we don’t support migration scenarios.

Comment: Also, we will clarify the documentation to state that `chatMessage.from` is read-only. Thanks for that.